Clang fails to instantiate `operator!=()` from `operator==()` with `auto` return type for a class object passed through a non-type template parameter
Consider the following code:
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T value;
    constexpr auto operator==(const T other) const {
        return value == other;
    }
};

template <Wrapper W>
void fun() {
    static_assert(W != 0); // This line fails on Clang
}

int main() {
    fun<Wrapper{1}>();
}

The above compiles successfully on GCC but fails to compile on Clang with the following error message:
<source>:11:21: error: return type 'auto' of selected 'operator==' function for rewritten '!=' comparison is not 'bool'
   11 |     static_assert(W != 0); // This line fails on Clang
      |                   ~ ^  ~
<source>:15:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fun<Wrapper<int>{1}>' requested here
   15 |     fun<Wrapper{1}>();
      |     ^
<source>:4:20: note: declared here
    4 |     constexpr auto operator==(const T other) const {
      |                    ^

Note that using bool instead of auto makes the program compile on both compilers.

However, interestingly enough, when I change the definition of fun() to this:
template <Wrapper W>
void fun() {
    void(W == 0); // Adding this line makes the error go away
    static_assert(W != 0);
}

It compiles fine on both compilers.
Alternatively, if I change the definition of the class Wrapper to not use a template parameter, it yet again successfully compiles on both compilers.

I believe this might a Clang/LLVM bug but I'm not sure if that's really the case.

Unsure if auto is supposed to work or not, but the fact that it starts working when you change fun() to the second snippet is definitely a bug.

Better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/dv51WjezY

This is a known clang bug (LLVM Issue 76649).
Firstly, note that the process of placeholder type deduction is described in Clause 9 of the standard, and it isn't said when that process actually takes place; that is up to the compiler. However, it is said to "replace" the placeholder type, and we we know that this has to happen prior to name lookup:

If a variable or function with an undeduced placeholder type is named by an expression ([basic.def.odr]), the program is ill-formed.

- [dcl.spec.auto.general] p11
Therefore, even with placeholder return types, the requirement in [over.match.oper] p10 should be satisfied:

If a rewritten operator== candidate is selected by overload resolution for an operator @, its return type shall be cv bool

At the point where this is verified, the placeholder type should have been replaced with bool.
Therefore, it's a clang bug that the selected operator== is not considered to have a bool return type.
As for:

void(W == 0); // Adding this line makes the error go away
static_assert(W != 0);


Clang correctly accepts this. I suspect that this works because the return type has been replaced by bool once W == 0 has run, and the subsequent W != 0 than piggybacks off of this.
Perhaps placeholder type deduction is somehow delayed or inhibited inside of unevaluated operands, which makes it fail when != is used in static_assert first.
